# If statement doesn't update

Tags: java, if-statement

I am learning java and i got stuck. I am using JTextField as userInput. After the user presses enter i want my if statement to print for me "text got changed". Afeter that i want to set 2 getters. First for my boolean and 2nd a string that contains user answer.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class setTextField{
    boolean gotChanged = false;
    String userInput;
    public void setTextField()
    {        
        Font fieldFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        JTextField test;
        test = new JTextField("Input here...");
        test.setBounds(widthPosition, 145, 220, 25);
        test.setFont(fieldFont);
        test.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        test.setForeground(Color.GRAY.brighter());
        test.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                gotChanged = true;
                userInput = test.getText();
            }
        });
        if(gotChanged)
        {
            System.out.println("Your answer is " + test);
        }
    }
    public boolean getInfo()
    {
        return gotChanged;
    }    
    public String getInput()
    {
        return userInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(gotChanged)
        {
            System.out.println("Your answer is " + test);
        }`
above code should be within `actionPerformed` method

Comment: Your if statement is called *once* on GUI creation, and it won't be magically called again in  your code as written. If you want it called on an event (button press), it needs to be placed within an event listener.

Comment: There is no button or something that can fire event to make listener.Add button or key listener.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `Sysout` into the `actionPerformed` method. You have no logic implemented to re-check the `if(gotChanged)`.

Comment: @Mextos: What do you mean by "my getter doesn't update"?  Be specific.  Currently this answer is correct, you need to check for a value after the user has entered the value, not before.  What other specific operation is failing in what way?